# Cannot Get LXC Container to Start

Tags: c++, c, containers, lxc

I am using LXC via the [C API](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/documentation/#c), and have simply copied and pasted the example code (as shown in that link, but replacing the `main` function name with my own). Then calling this from within another block of code in my program, I cannot get the container to start properly.

The call to `start` simply returns false. If I change the second parameter to start to 0 (implying that `lxcinit` should be used instead of /sbin/init), then start "succeeds", but the container state is immediately set to `STOPPED`, and so I cannot attach to the container.

Attempting to get logs by setting:

```
c->set_config_item(c, "lxc.logfile", "/home/user/lxc-log.log");
c->set_config_item(c, "lxc.logpriority", "TRACE");
c->set_config_item(c, "lxc.console.logfile", "/home/user/lxc-log2.log");
c->set_config_item(c, "lxc.console.logpriority", "TRACE");
```

Just produces empty files.

Thinking that this may be related to [another issue I saw](https://serverfault.com/questions/646176/lxc-container-not-starting), I also tried setting:

```
c->set_config_item(c, "lxc.aa_allow_incomplete", "1");
```

Creating a separate C++ program, and compiling it works like a charm, but when I attempt to call it from within another program, by simply adding a function and calling it (specifically [a uni project](https://github.com/joshbambrick/firmament/blob/master/src/engine/executors/local_executor.cc)), I cannot get it to run properly at all.

Comment: I'd start off with deciding for a single language and removing the tag for the other language. Then, read the description of the other tags and decide whether they are appropriate. Then, read the posting guidelines and provide enough info for others to reproduce your issue. Be precise though!

Comment: I'd say both languages are useful, since the API is for C, but the project we are developing is in C++. One can reproduce my issue by building the project I link to, calling the function I described (also linked). I am attempting to determine a minimal case for creating this issue, and will keep the post up-to-date, as my work develops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I was able to solve this issue by disabling two packages that were included as part of the larger project tcmalloc, and asan.